# how to use slug in my route instead of an id

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to use *slug* in my route instead of the *id* but it is returning a 404 response. I have tried all resources I could use. Please help me. This is my web URL

```
<a href="{{route('blog.show' , $blog->id)}}"> 
<button id="readmore" class="btn-primary 
mb-5 btn-xl">Read More</button></a>
```

This is my controller action:

```
public function showPost(Blog $blog)
{
    $comments = $blog
        ->comments()
        ->with(['blogs'])
        ->paginate(5);
    return view('web.single-post', [
        'blog' => $blog,
        'comments' => $comments,
    ]);
}
```

This is my route definition:

```
Route::get('/blog/{blog:slug}', [
    App\Http\Controllers\WelcomeController::class,
    'showPost'
])->name('blog.show');
```

Finally, this is my model:

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
```

Comment: you could just pass the model to the `route` helper and not specifically the `id` attribute (it will figure out what value to use based on the `getRouteKeyName` method which `getRouteKey` uses)

Comment: @Tanmay Thank you. It work but changed the font size of my text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `{{route('blog.show' , $blog->id)}}` to `{{route('blog.show' , $blog->slug)}}`